# function return undefined, instead of true/false boolean expr when calling

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to check for a slug if already exist using Javascript NodeJs, Bookshelf...

So far I have this code which is actually not working:

```
var makeSlug = function (slug) {
    var baseSlug = slug;
    var i = 1;
    //console.log("RETURN: " +  slug_exists(slug));
    while (slug_exists(slug)) {
        slug = baseSlug + '-' + i;
        i++;
    }
    return slug;
};

var slug_exists = function (album) {
    new Album({slug: slugify(album)})
        .fetch()
        .then(function (album) {
            if (album) {
                console.log("trueee");
                return true;
            } else {
                console.log("falseee");
                return false;
            }
        });
};
```

And somewhere in the code I call this function as var newSlug = makeSlug('Endless River');
It seems like slug_exists function doesnt return me true eventhou it prints "trueee", therefore while loop also doesnt work...
Any suggestion, help how would you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return like that, inside of a promise's callback (as it will be the `return` for *that* function, not the outer one).

Since you have a promise already, return that and let `makeSlug()` check the `then()`.

```
var slug_exists = function (album) {
    return new Album({slug: slugify(album)}).fetch();
};
```

Comment: alex, how did u mean to do then() inside make_slug function?